# Implement pattern match on FindUsersByName

Tags: c#

I would like some feedback on the code below. And how would I Implement pattern match on find users in role so that exact match not required?

```
// MembershipProvider.FindUsersByName       
public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
{
    MembershipUserCollection users = new MembershipUserCollection();

    try
    {
        Profile.MembershipMapper memberMapper = new MembershipMapper();
        List<Profile.Membership> recs = (List<Profile.Membership>)memberMapper.GetMembershipsByUsername(_memberUtil.GetApplicationId(), usernameToMatch, pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords);

        foreach (Profile.Membership rec in recs)
        {
            users.Add(GetUserFromModel(rec, usernameToMatch));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Exception e = CheckEventLog(ex, "FindUsersByName");
        throw e;
    }

    return users;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Profile.Membership> recs = (List<Profile.Membership>)memberMapper.GetMembershipsByUsername(_memberUtil.GetApplicationId(), usernameToMatch, pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords);
```

I don't understand why is the cast needed here, `GetMembershipsByUsername()` doesn't sound like a method for which a cast would be necessary.

Also, I think you should consider using `var` here, especially if you're going to keep the cast, so the type of the variable is clear. (I would probably use `var` even without the cast, but that's more debatable.)

```
Exception e = CheckEventLog(ex, "FindUsersByName");
throw e;
```

I don't see any reason for the (not very well named) variable `e` here, just `throw` the exception directly:

```
throw CheckEventLog(ex, "FindUsersByName");
```

Also, I think the method name `CheckEventLog()` could be improved. It's not clear at all that it returns an `Exception`, or what that exception means.

```
return users;
```

I would move this before the end of the `try`. That way, it's clearer that the method either returns a meaningful result or throws an exception. (And if you changed that later by removing or limiting the `throw`, you would get a compile error, which I think is a plus.)

Also, doing this means you can move the declaration of the `users` variable into the `try` too.